# How can I get all top 50 users by most sales in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am trying to query users who has most product sales on last month.
Is there any way to do it to fetch the top 50 post authors who has most product sales on last month.
Currently I am just querying through wp users query to fetch 50 vendors but can't order them through sales report.

```
 $current_page = $_GET['page-num'] ? (int) $_GET['page-num'] : 1;
    $users_per_page = 50; // RAISE THIS AFTER TESTING ;)

    $args = array(
            'role' => 'Vendor',
            'number' => $users_per_page, // How many per page
            'paged' => $current_page, // What page to get, starting from 1.
            'orderby' => 'login',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        );
    $users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

If anybody have any idea regarding this please help.Thanks a lot in advanced.

**More modification:**

Now I have made this code which fetch top 50 vendors but notaccording to last month sales.

```
global $wpdb; 
$atts = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $atts );
$posts = implode( ',', $posts->posts );

$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_author,SUM(meta.meta_value) AS total_sales FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta ON (wp_posts.ID = meta.post_id) WHERE ID IN ($posts) AND meta.meta_key = 'total_sales' GROUP BY post_author ORDER BY total_sales DESC LIMIT 50" );
```